# Placing Boats in Battleship (Removing Code Duplication)

Tags: common-lisp, code-duplication

I'm (slowly) working out a 2D version of Battleship now that my 1D version is done. I wrote the following function to place a boat on the board given the length of the boat, the position of the boat, and the direction the boat is facing. However, the function is ugly. Very ugly. By which I mean, there is much in the way of code duplication. Could anyone point out some ways in which I could reduce the duplication in this code?

```
(defun place-boat (len pos dir)
  (let ((offset 0))
    (dotimes (i len)
      (if (= dir 0)
        (if (< pos 50)
          (setf (aref *ans-board*
              (+ (/ pos 10) offset)
              (mod pos 10))
            '#)
          (setf (aref *ans-board*
              (- (/ pos 10) offset)
              (mod pos 10))
            '#))
        (if (< pos 50)
          (setf (aref *ans-board*
              (/ pos 10)
              (+ (mod pos 10) offset))
            '#)
          (setf (aref *ans-board*
              (/ pos 10)
              (- (mod pos 10) offset))
            '#)))
      (incf offset))))
```

**EDIT**: For clarification, `pos` is a number between 1 and 100, signifying a cell in a 10x10 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, I don't think you need both i and offset.  They both go from 0 up to len in step with each other.

Then you could do something like this to collapse the +/- cases for < or >= 50 into one statement:

`(+ (/ pos 10) (* (if (< pos 50) 1 -1) offset))`

That give you (untested):

```
(defun place-boat (len pos dir)
  (dotimes (offset len)
    (if (= dir 0)
      (setf (aref *ans-board*
                  (+ (/ pos 10) (* (if (< pos 50) 1 -1) offset))
                  (mod pos 10))
            '#)
      (setf (aref *ans-board*
                  (/ pos 10)
                  (+ (mod pos 10) (* (if (< pos 50) 1 -1) offset)))
            '#))))
```

which still has some redundancy.  But that's what I've got so far.

Note, I know very little about Common Lisp, so I'm sure someone else could do much better :)

Comment: With some help from the fine folks in #lisp, I tweaked your solution a bit and ended up with this: http://paste.lisp.org/display/117875#3 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Supposed I understand your needs correctly:
if you would deal with the directions -1,-1,10,-10 you could easily do something like this:

```
(defun place (pos len dir) 
    (loop for i from pos to (+ pos (* len dir)) by dir do 
       (setf (aref board i) '\#)))
```

Comment: That would work, but the array being dealt with is 2-dimensional. :/